# Korrekte Schreibweise von »Data Science«

Tags: spelling, compound, hyphen

Wie wird der englischsprachige Fachbegriff »Data Science« korrekterweise in deutschsprachigen Texten geschrieben?

Laut dem [Duden](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Schreibung-von-Fremdwortern-aus-dem-Englischen) müssten die beiden Wörter zusammengeschrieben werden, da es sich um zwei Substantive handelt. Also wäre Datascience oder Data-Science die korrekte Schreibweise. Jedoch konnte ich kaum deutschsprachige Publikationen finden, in denen diese Schreibweise tatsächlich genutzt wurde. Hingegen scheint die Schreibweise Data Science ohne Bindestrich am gebräuchlichsten zu sein. Was ist nun korrekt?

Comment: Warum nicht einfach pragmatisch _Data Science_ akzeptieren, und Duden und Regelparagraphen ignorieren? Es sieht dann einfach besser aus.

Comment: Die Regeln sind hier auch ein bißchen wirr: Warum sie "Hot Dog" akzeptieren, aber "Data Science" nicht, leuchtet mir nur schwer ein. Der deutsche Anwender sollte nicht wissen müssen, wo denn im englischen Original ein Adjektiv oder ein Substantiv war.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Es gibt laut den Regeln des Rechtschreibrates zwei verschiedene Möglichkeiten, ein eingedeutschtes Kompositum zu schreiben:

> §45 E1: Aus anderen Sprachen stammende Verbindungen aus Substantiv + Substantiv, die sich im Deutschen grammatisch wie Zusammensetzungen verhalten, werden zusammengeschrieben; ebenso ist die verdeutlichende Schreibung mit Bindestrich möglich: Sexappeal (Sex-Appeal), Sciencefiction (Science-Fiction), Shoppingcenter (Shopping-Center), Desktoppublishing (Desktop-Publishing), Midlifecrisis (Midlife-Crisis)

Folglich wären

> Datascience

(in seiner ganzen Gruseligkeit) und

> Data-Science

richtig.

Comment: Fällt denn der Begriff »Data Science« schon unter die deutschen Orthografieregeln oder kann er eventuell auch als Fremdzitat (Vergleich [Duden D39](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/fremdwoerter)) betrachtet und damit unverändert in deutschen Texten übernommen werden?

Comment: @Eighe Dann müsste man aber "data science" schreiben und nicht "Data Science".

Comment: Wenn du bereit bist, das fremde Compound in Anführungszeichen zu setzen (auch wenn du es dann nicht tust), dann ja. Ich selbst würde mir wahrscheinlich einfach keinen Kopf machen und *Data Science* schreiben. Ich finde die Bindestrichschreibung (noch) akzeptabel, aber Zusammenschreibung fürchterlich.